# connect to a MySQL server in an instance in google cloud server

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Good evening everyone! I'm new on cloud servers, I made a google cloud VM instance where I installed mysql and then configured a db, when I try to access this database from my own computer it denies the connection with:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '>instanceIP<'
```

I made the firewall rule in the port 3306, I don't know what else to do.

Comment: I don't understand your tags **at all*.  You said you made a VM instance (presumably Google Compute Engine) and tried connecting to it from your computer.  What does Google App Engine have to do with it?  What does Google Cloud SQL have to do with it?  Why no Google Compute Engine tag?  Please edit your Q to fix your tags OR to fix the text so it matches the tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!!!!, made a Cloud SQL instance and added the other instance IP to the accesses.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue but don't understand your answer. Can you please elaborate?